# Why isn't my ListSearchExtender (ASP.NET AjaxControlToolkit) registered correctly?

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am unable to get the List Search Extender from the Ajax Control Toolkit to work correctly.  I get the error: "Could not load file or assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

I followed the installation instructions for Visual Studio 2010 as [found here](http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/).  I see the AjaxControlToolkit listed in the references section of my solution and I have registered the assembly as shown in my code below.  What am I doing incorrectly?

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="asp" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit"%>

<asp:ListBox ID="VendorSelector" runat="server"></asp:ListBox>
<asp:ListSearchExtender id="LSE" runat="server"
  TargetControlID="VendorSelector"
  PromptText="Type to search"
  PromptCssClass="ListSearchExtenderPrompt"
  PromptPosition="Top"
  AutoResetTimeout="0"
  QueryPattern="Contains"
  IsSorted="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had not added the assembly to my project package.  I did not realize that adding the reference and registering the assembly via code was not enough.

I also needed to add the public key token and version to the registration tag.